# Group by a column and selecting rows of another column with the maximum character in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, string, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataset where I want to select the corresponding rows with the maximum character for each `ID`.
This is a summary of the data

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,1,3),
                 text=c("new town","car is sold","address is changed","to be confirmed","call later")) 
df %>% glimpse()
```

```
Rows: 5
Columns: 2
$ id   <dbl> 1, 2, 2, 1, 3
$ text <chr> "new town", "car is sold", "address is changed",~
```

And I am trying this code to select those rows that had the max number of characters but it seems something is not working.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(text==max(str_length(text)))
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# Groups:   id [0]
# ... with 2 variables: id <dbl>, text <chr>
```

I hope it is clear and someone can help.

Many thanks!

Comment: It needs to be `str_length(text) == max(str_length(text)` - your current code is asking if the string literal ("new town") equal to a number, which it will never be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (slightly adapted your code):

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  filter(str_length(text)==max(str_length(text)), .by = id)
```

```
 id               text
1  2 address is changed
2  1    to be confirmed
3  3         call later
```

As an alternative we could use `which.max` with `nchar`:

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  filter(row_number()==which.max(nchar(text)), .by = id)

  id               text
1  2 address is changed
2  1    to be confirmed
3  3         call later
```

Comment: ```Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of
  size 4 or 1, not size 0``` it's what I got when I tried on the real data. Not sure what it means

Comment: My guess your data frame is empty. Check the version of dplyr. It should be up to date. Or try: `library(dplyr) df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==which.max(nchar(text))) %>% 
  ungroup()`

Comment: that's what I got again:  ```In group 327:
 ID =100250. Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of
  size 4 or 1, not size 0``` could it be because some of the rows have no texts and there are "NAs" there?